# ConnectNamedPipe разблокировать поток

Tags: delphi, winapi

Здравствуйте. Пишу класс, создающий серверный экземпляр именованного канала. Работа осуществляется в *синхронном режиме*.

При вызове метода `Free` мне необходимо, чтобы поток, в котором читается пайп, корректно завершался. Но проблема в том, что `ConnectNamedPipe` блокирует дальнейшее выполнение, если нет клиента.

Есть функция `CancelSynchronousIo`, но, как я понимаю, она отсутствует в ОС ниже Vista, а создавать в другом потоке клиент или TerminateThread - это совсем неправильно.

Как можно разблокировать поток?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Читайте [документацию](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365146%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), там все доступно написано.
Создаете пайп с флагом `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` и тогда ваш поток выйдет из метода `ConnectNamedPipe` сразуже и не будет заблокирован. При успешном выполнении метода, `GetLastError` должен вернуть `ERROR_IO_PENDING`. Проверить завершилась ли операция ввода/вывода можно вызовом метода `HasOverlappedIoCompleted` ([документация](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683244%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). Метод вернет `True`, если операция завершена.

Также `OVERLAPPED` структура содержит ивент, который система сама установит в сигнальное состояние после завершения операции. Таким образом вызвав метод `ConnectNamedPipe` Вы можете ожидать в потоке одно из двух событий (завершение операции или прерывание работы потока). Второе событие вам нужно будет включать самостоятельно когда нужно будет завершить поток, например, в методе `Destroy`. Включили событие, подождали `WaitFor`, продолжили уничтожение потока.